# Integrate zoomIn and zoomout from animation.css to Jquery Mobile and also transitions lightSpeedIn and lightSpeedout

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, css-transitions

I am using animate.css from http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ and there are 2 cool transtions which I would like to integrate or customize to my jquery mobile applications one of them is zoomIn and zoomOut and the other one is lightSpeedIn and lightSpeedout.... If any of you have already implemented them as a custom transitions for your mobile projects... please let me know how...

For example this customization is for bounceIn Transtions:

```
.bounceIn.in {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);

    -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
    -moz-animation-name: bounceIn;  
    -ms-animation-name: bounceIn;
    -o-animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-name: bounceIn;

    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 750ms;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-duration: 750ms;
}

.bounceIn.out {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);   

    -webkit-animation-name: bounceOut;
    -moz-animation-name: bounceOut;
    -ms-animation-name: bounceOut;
    -o-animation-name: bounceOut;
    animation-name: bounceOut;

    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 555ms;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-duration: 555;
```

}

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this blog article I wrote about using animate.css for jQM page transitions:

> **[CUSTOM PAGE TRANSITIONS (PART 1)](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/custom-page-transitions-part-1/)**

To use Lightspeed animation:

```
.customLightSpeed.in {
    -webkit-animation-name: lightSpeedIn;
    -moz-animation-name: lightSpeedIn;
    animation-name: lightSpeedIn;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 750ms;
    -moz-animation-duration: 750ms;
    animation-duration: 750ms;
}
.customLightSpeed.out {
    -webkit-animation-name: lightSpeedOut;
    -moz-animation-name: lightSpeedOut;
    animation-name: lightSpeedOut;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms;
    -moz-animation-duration: 500ms;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
}
```

Then in your link, set the data-transition attribute to the class you created.

```
<a href="#page2" data-transition="customLightSpeed">
```

To use Zoom animation:

```
.customZoomTrans.in {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
    -moz-animation-name: zoomIn;
    animation-name: zoomIn;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 600ms;
    -moz-animation-duration: 600ms;
    animation-duration: 600ms;
}
.customZoomTrans.out {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoomOut;
    -moz-animation-name: zoomOut;
    animation-name: zoomOut;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms;
    -moz-animation-duration: 500ms;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
}
```

You can tweak the animation-duration values to get the speed you desire.

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hcNf5/)**

Also in the demo I included a zoom transition with reverse directions:

```
.customZoomTrans2.in {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoomInLeft;
    -moz-animation-name: zoomInLeft;
    animation-name: zoomInLeft;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms;
    -moz-animation-duration: 500ms;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
}
.customZoomTrans2.out {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoomOutRight;
    -moz-animation-name: zoomOutRight;
    animation-name: zoomOutRight;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 400ms;
    -moz-animation-duron: 400ms;
    animation-duration: 400ms;
}
.customZoomTrans2.in.reverse {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoomInRight;
    -moz-animation-name: zoomInRight;
    animation-name: zoomInRight;
}
.customZoomTrans2.out.reverse {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoomOutLeft;
    -moz-animation-name: zoomOutLeft;
    animation-name: zoomOutLeft;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ezanker for your help. This is exactly what I needed... I will take a look at http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/custom-page-transitions-part-1/ to get acquainted with other amazing transitions provided by animation.css and of course customed by YOU. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `animated` class along with any animate css effects.

So, Your Html will be like following.

```
<div class="animated bounceIn" >
Animated Demo
</div>
```

For Live Demo [Check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/9Gxcu/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your comments Husen ... that I already know how to implement... I am referring to the ones that I specified in the subject of this question... How do I implement a page transition with Jquery Mobile using zoomIn and zoomOut and the other one is lightSpeedIn and lightSpeedout...

Answer (score 0):

So, You need that css animation effects on page scroll? right?

Its tricky but not so hard.

First of all you have to add `animated` and `inview` class to whatever section you need to apply animation.

SO, your html will be like following.

```
<p style="margin-bottom:900px">FOr Long Scroll Only</p>
<p class="inview animated">Html Value</p>
```

After that you need to write one small JQuery function like following.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){})
jQuery('.inview').bind('inview',function(event,visible)
{
    if(visible==true)
    {
        jQuery('.animated').addClass("bounceIn");
    }
    else{jQuery('.animated').removeClass("bounceIn");}
});
```

[Please check this link for live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/9Gxcu/2/)